# Create table in android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

Error : android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table User has no column named name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO User(name,balance,password,age) VALUES (?,?,?,?)

```
public class NewUserTable {

    int _id;
    String _name;
    String _password;
    int _balance;
    int _age;
    public NewUserTable(){

    }
    public NewUserTable( String name, String password, int balance, int age){
        this._name = name;
        this._password = password;
        this._balance = balance;
        this._age = age;
    }
    public NewUserTable( int id, String name, String password, int balance, int age){
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
        this._password = password;
        this._balance = balance;
        this._age = age;
    }
    public  int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this._name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this._name = name;
    }
    public String getPassword(){
        return this._password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password){
        this._password = password;
    }
    public int getBalance(){
        return _balance;
    }
    public void setBalance(int balance){
        this._balance = balance;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return _age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age){
        this._age = age;
    }
}
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
//----------- TABLE COLUMNS -----------//
public static final String KEY_ID = "id"; // eash user has unique id
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String KEY_BALANCE = "balance";
public static final String KEY_AGE ="age";
//----------- TABLE COLUMNS -----------//
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "newUser";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "User";
public DatabaseHandler(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String CREATE_NEWUSER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
        + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME +
        "TEXT," + KEY_PASSWORD + "TEXT," + KEY_BALANCE + "INTEGER,"
        + KEY_AGE + "INTEGER" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_NEWUSER_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public int getUsersCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();
    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
// добавить новую запись
public void addUser(NewUserTable newUserTable){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME,newUserTable.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD,newUserTable.getPassword());
    values.put(KEY_BALANCE,newUserTable.getBalance());
    values.put(KEY_AGE,newUserTable.getAge());
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
// считать записи
public NewUserTable getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                    KEY_NAME, KEY_PASSWORD, KEY_BALANCE, KEY_AGE }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    NewUserTable newUserTable = new NewUserTable(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)),
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));
    // return contact
    return newUserTable;
}
```

}

```
public class CreateUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText etName;
EditText etPassword;
EditText etBalance;
EditText etAge;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_user);
}

public void CreateUser(View view) {
    etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    etBalance = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etBalance);
    etAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    String name = String.valueOf(etName.getText());
    String password = String.valueOf(etPassword.getText());
    int balance = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(etBalance.getText()));
    int age = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(etAge.getText()));

    //write to database from our edit texts
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
    db.addUser(new NewUserTable(name,password,balance,age));
}
```

}
Where is the problem? And how can i see the database result?

Comment: can you post your database handler file. ? and error log for quicker solutions ?

Comment: code class of database handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
String CREATE_NEWUSER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
    + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME +
    "TEXT," + KEY_PASSWORD + "TEXT," + KEY_BALANCE + "INTEGER,"
    + KEY_AGE + "INTEGER" + ")";
```

with

```
String CREATE_NEWUSER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_NAME +
    " TEXT, " + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT, " + KEY_BALANCE + " INTEGER, "
    + KEY_AGE + " INTEGER" + ")";
```

You missed few blank spaces in the create table script.

Comment: Error inserting name=sssss balance=15 password=ss age=22                                                               android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table User has no column named name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO User(name,balance,password,age) VALUES (?,?,?,?)

Comment: After changing the code you need to uninstall the app and install again.

Comment: do you mean to Android device?

Comment: remove your app from android phone/tablet and install again. Don't just re-run.

Comment: Go to the app listing and long press the app icon. You will get the uninstall option.

Comment: app - > change configuration -> defaults - > Remove - > rebuild and run the app? I do it and exception E/SQLiteLog: (1) table User has no column named name E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=sss balance=15 password=ssss age=22

Comment: Unistall from the device or emulator on which app is running. Don't do anything in the Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> String CREATE_NEWUSER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
>     + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME +
>     "TEXT," + KEY_PASSWORD + "TEXT," + KEY_BALANCE + "INTEGER,"
>     + KEY_AGE + "INTEGER" + ")";
> ```

You need whitespace between your column names and column types.

After adding the spaces, uninstall your app so that your SQLite helper's `onCreate()` is invoked again.

Comment: Error inserting name=sssss balance=15 password=ss age=22 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table User has no column named name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO User(name,balance,password,age) VALUES (?,?,?,?)

Comment: Did you also uninstall the app to recreate the database?

Comment: I close the app and re-run your changed version.

Comment: That does not remove the old database with column names such as `nameTEXT`.

Answer (score -2):

If you modify something at this string you need to uninstall the app and run again, in order to changes apply. Other else the modification doesn;t apply because.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32839109)